# Calling and writing a fuction containing ditionary keys and values

Tags: c#, function, dictionary

I'm currently making a small little game in C# and I have run into a small little problem that I can't seem to find the answer to, and I'm sorry if this question is too amateur, I really have tried searching a lot of stuff, maybe I'm using the wrong keywords etc.

Either way, I'm trying to make a function that writes out the current values of different keys in my dictionary, each while loop.

I've written a bit more about what I'm looking for in the comments of the code block -
Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace MyApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> rutor =
                new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // Add some elements to the dictionary. There are no
            // duplicate keys, but some of the values are duplicates.
            rutor.Add("a1", "*");
            rutor.Add("a2", "*");
            rutor.Add("a3", "*");
            rutor.Add("a4", "*");
            rutor.Add("b1", "*");
            rutor.Add("b2", "*");
            rutor.Add("b3", "*");
            rutor.Add("b4", "*");
            rutor.Add("c1", "*");
            rutor.Add("c2", "*");
            rutor.Add("c3", "*");
            rutor.Add("c4", "*");
            rutor.Add("d1", "*");
            rutor.Add("d2", "*");
            rutor.Add("d3", "*");
            rutor.Add("d4", "*");

            //My very basic dictionary!
            //And what im now trying to do is creating a function that grabs these values 
            //and prints out the following by JUST calling the function, instead of writing    
            //these MANY lines! C#


            Console.Write($"{rutor["a1"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["a2"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["a3"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["a4"]}  a1  a2  a3  a4\n");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["b1"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["b2"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["b3"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["b4"]}  b1  b1  b3  b3\n");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["c1"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["c2"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["c3"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["c4"]}  c1  c2  c3  c4\n");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["d1"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["d2"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["d3"]} ");
            Console.Write($"{rutor["d4"]}  d1  d2  d3  d4\n");



            //Very messy code, but im just learning so hope you guys have a solutino to this                           
            // "inconvenience"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
public static void PrintDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dic)
    {
    StringBuilder valueSb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder keySb = new StringBuilder();
    int iterationCount = 0;
    foreach (var item in dic)
      {
      // value
      valueSb.Append(item.Value);
      valueSb.Append(" ");

      // key
      keySb.Append(item.Key);
      keySb.Append("  ");

      iterationCount++;

      if (iterationCount == 4)
        {
        Console.Write(valueSb + " ");
        Console.Write(keySb.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        iterationCount = 0;
        valueSb.Clear();
        keySb.Clear();
        }
      }
    }
```

You can call the function like this.

```
PrintDictionary(rutor);
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i was lookin for! It was this part that i did not figure out
(Dictionary<string, string> dic) <- +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach for this [learn more](https://executor%20failed%20running%20%5B/bin/sh%20-c%20/bin/gaiad%20init%20Edima%5D:%20exit%20code:%201) to iterate through your collection (dictionary).

```
foreach(var item in rutor)
{
    Console.Write($"{item.Value}");
}
```

Comment: Could surely work, but i need the values written in a 4x4 format:

And it would be alot easier to do that with just calling the function with the pre-existing code.

Comment: You know how to write a method? (In c# we call all functions like that)

Answer (score 0):

From your code sample, it seems like you want to list each [possibly duplicated] value in your dictionary, with each key related key.

If so, you can use `System.Linq` and do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyApplication
{
  public static class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      Dictionary<string, string> rutor = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
        // Add some elements to the dictionary. There are no
        // duplicate keys, but some of the values are duplicates.
        {"a1", "v1"},
        {"a2", "v2"},
        {"a3", "v1"},
        {"a4", "v3"},
        {"b1", "v4"},
        {"b2", "v1"},
        {"b3", "v3"},
        {"b4", "v4"},
        {"c1", "v1"},
        {"c2", "v5"},
        {"c3", "v3"},
        {"c4", "v1"},
        {"d1", "v2"},
        {"d2", "*"},
        {"d3", "v1"},
        {"d4", "*"},
      };
      
      // A Dictionary<Tkey,Tvalue> is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Tkey,Tvalue> does the following:
      // - iterates over the key/value pairs in the dictionary,
      // - groups the keys by value, so now we have an enumerablie list of groups,
      //   each of which has a key and is itself an enumerable list of values.
      // - Each such group is then turned into a dictionary entry
      
      Dictionary<string,List<string>> keysByValue =
        rutor
        .GroupBy( tuple => tuple.Value , tuple => tuple.Key )
        .ToDictionary(
          g => g.Key,
          g => g.OrderBy( x => x ).ToList()
        );
      
      foreach (var kvp in keysByValue)
      {
        string value = kvp.Key ;
        string keys  = string.Join( " ",  kvp.Value );
        
        Console.WriteLine( "value: {0} keys: {1}", value , keys );
        
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Another (possibly simpler) approach is to roll your own.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyApplication
{
  public static class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      Dictionary<string, string> rutor = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
        // Add some elements to the dictionary. There are no
        // duplicate keys, but some of the values are duplicates.
        {"a1", "v1"},
        {"a2", "v2"},
        {"a3", "v1"},
        {"a4", "v3"},
        {"b1", "v4"},
        {"b2", "v1"},
        {"b3", "v3"},
        {"b4", "v4"},
        {"c1", "v1"},
        {"c2", "v5"},
        {"c3", "v3"},
        {"c4", "v1"},
        {"d1", "v2"},
        {"d2", "*"},
        {"d3", "v1"},
        {"d4", "*"},
      };
        
      Dictionary<string,List<string>> keysByValue = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
      foreach (var kvp in rutor)
      {
          List<string> values;
          bool exists = keysByValue.TryGetValue( kvp.Value, out values );
          if ( !exists )
          {
              values = new List<string>();
              keysByValue[ kvp.Value ] = values;
          }
          values.Add( kvp.Key );
      }
     
      foreach (string value in keysByValue.Keys.OrderBy( s => s ) )
      {
        string keys = string.Join( " ",  keysByValue[value] );
        Console.WriteLine( "value: {0} keys: {1}", value , keys );
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```